# Заполнение пользовательского SVG progress bar

Tags: javascript, html, css3, svg, анимация

В своей простейшей форме я хочу сделать страницу загрузки, такую как на [этом сайте](http://www.tilljanz.com/).

Я хочу использовать собственный логотип SVG (который я сделал в иллюстраторе) и горизонтально заполнять логотип при загрузке страницы.

Как `progress bar` клипирования маски SVG (или что-то похожее).

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Custom SVG progress bar fill](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30801976/7394871) от участника  [@user3439936](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3439936/user3439936).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/30801976/7394871

Answer (score 4):

Самый простой способ сделать это - заполнить лого с помощью градиента.

```
<linearGradient id="progress">
   <stop id="stop1" offset="0" stop-color="black"/>
   <stop id="stop2" offset="0" stop-color="grey"/>
</linearGradient>`
```

Вам просто нужно изменить значение `offset` на обоих элементах `<stop>` на процент, который вы хотите - либо `0-> 1`, либо `0%` -> `100%`. Например:

Функция может быть примерно такой:

```
function setProgress(amt)
{
  amt = (amt < 0) ? 0 : (amt > 1) ? 1 : amt;
  document.getElementById("stop1").setAttribute("offset", amt);
  document.getElementById("stop2").setAttribute("offset", amt);
}
```

Этот подход работает для любого элемента SVG, будь то текст, как в приведенной ниже демонстрационной версии, или сложный логотип из путей.

```js
function setProgress(amt)
{
  amt = (amt < 0) ? 0 : (amt > 1) ? 1 : amt;
  document.getElementById("stop1").setAttribute("offset", amt);
  document.getElementById("stop2").setAttribute("offset", amt);
}

  
// Простой тест setProgress().
// Мы переходим от 0 до 1, используя таймауты
val = 0;
doTimeout();

function doTimeout() {
  setProgress(val);
  val += 0.01;
  if (val <= 1) {
    setTimeout(doTimeout, 30);
  }
}
```

```css
text {
  font: 'Times Roman', serif;
  font-size: 125px;
  fill: url(#progress);
}
```

```html
<svg width="650" height="150">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="progress">
      <stop id="stop1" offset="0" stop-color="black"/>
      <stop id="stop2" offset="0" stop-color="grey"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

  <text x="20" y="120">TILL JANZ</text>
</svg>
```

**Ещё пример - сезонная смена цвета  деревьев**

```js
function setProgress(amt)
{
  amt = (amt < 0) ? 0 : (amt > 1) ? 1 : amt;
  document.getElementById("stop1").setAttribute("offset", amt);
  document.getElementById("stop2").setAttribute("offset", amt);
}

  
// Simple test of setProgress().
// We step up from 0 to 1 using timeouts
val = 0;
doTimeout();

function doTimeout() {
  setProgress(val);
  val += 0.01;
  if (val <= 1) {
    setTimeout(doTimeout, 30);
  }
}
```

```css
#tree1 {
  fill: url(#progress);
}
```

```html
<svg width="267" height="347" viewBox="0 0 267 347">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="progress">
      <stop id="stop1" offset="0" stop-color="#D3B300"/>
      <stop id="stop2" offset="0" stop-color="green"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

  <g id="tree1">
  <path id="Trunk" d="m119 262 28 0 0 86-28-2z"  style="fill:#502d16;stroke:#000"/>
  <path id="Leaves" d="M261 327 169 244c16 9 103 34 76 15-25-18-81-74-81-74 8 5 94 45 71 27-24-19-78-88-78-88 7 5 42 11 42 11-24-13-47-73-47-73 11 8 21 7 21 7C149 51 133 0 133 0c0 0-15 51-39 69 0 0 9 1 21-7 0 0-23 60-47 73 0 0 35-7 42-12 0 0-38 58-78 89-20 15 61-23 69-28 0 0-25 38-75 85-14 14 63-13 72-25 0 0-70 64-88 86-6 7 123-56 123-56 0 0 133 70 129 52z"  /> 
  </g>
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30802965/7394871) от участника  [@Paul LeBeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292848/paul-lebeau).</sub>